# Multi-argument function not working with dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am unable to run the below code.

I had defined a function that takes multiple arguments. When hard coding the data the function works but when applying the function to the dataframe - it is not working. I have used the "apply" function earlier with no argument in a dataframe - they work fine but as soon as I use this function with multi arguments it throws an error.

```
import pandas as pd
import mibian

def IV(spot,strike,premium,cp):
    interest_rate = 10
    days_to_expiry = 11
    if cp == 'CE':
        c = mibian.BS([spot,strike,interest_rate,days_to_expiry],callPrice=premium)
        return c.impliedVolatility
    else:
        c = mibian.BS([spot,strike,interest_rate,days_to_expiry],putPrice=premium)
        return c.impliedVolatility

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Symbol": ['a','b','c','d'],
        "Spot":[100,200,300,400],
        "Strike":[105,205,305,405],
        "CP":['CE','PE','CE','PE'],
        "LTP":[2,3,4,5]
    }
)

df['IV'] = IV(df.Spot,df.Strike,df.LTP,df.CP)

**#df['IV'] = IV(100,105,5,'PE').round(decimals=2)**

df['IV'] = df['IV'].round(decimals=2)
print(df)
```

I get the below error msg

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Arishka/Desktop/Python/iv_greeks.py", line 27, in <module>
    df['IV'] = IV(df.Spot,df.Strike,df.LTP,df.CP)
  File "c:/Users/Arishka/Desktop/Python/iv_greeks.py", line 10, in IV
    if cp == 'CE':
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1552, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import mibian

def IV(x):
    spot, strike, premium, cp = x
    interest_rate = 10
    days_to_expiry = 11
    if cp == 'CE':
        c = mibian.BS([spot, strike, interest_rate, days_to_expiry], callPrice=premium)
        return c.impliedVolatility
    elif cp == 'PE':
        c = mibian.BS([spot, strike, interest_rate, days_to_expiry], putPrice=premium)
        return c.impliedVolatility

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Symbol": ['a','b','c','d'],
        "Spot":[100,200,300,400],
        "Strike":[105,205,305,405],
        "CP":['CE','PE','CE','PE'],
        "LTP":[2,3,4,5]
    }
)

df['IV'] = df[['Spot', 'Strike', 'LTP', 'CP']].apply(IV, axis=1)
```

result

```
    Symbol  Spot    Strike  CP  LTP IV
0   a       100     105     CE  2   54.687500
1   b       200     205     PE  3   0.000010
2   c       300     305     CE  4   27.832031
3   d       400     405     PE  5   9.765625
```